# Deserialize Json Array using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I have an array of objects like this in json as per below format

```
[{"GroupID":5},{"GroupID":47}]
```

What's the correct way to deserialize it?

I have the Group object:

```
 public class Group
    {
        [JsonProperty("GroupID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to deserialize by:

```
Group[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Group[]>(json).Select(j => j.Group).ToArray()
```

but I get a compiler error - probably due to a missing linking class:

> 'Group' does not contain a definition for 'Group' and no extension
>   method 'Group' accepting a first argument of type 'Group' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Select(j => j.Group)
```

Means: "select the **property** `Group` from all the elements in the array".

You don't have a property called `Group`, you have a class called `Group`.

All you need is:

```
Group[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Group[]>(json)
```